# Can I find out the return value before returning while debugging in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging

Take the following function:

```
func go() {
    return someTablePresenter.getSomeData();
}
```

When I set a breakpoint in this function, is there a possibility to inspect the returned value?

The only way to inspect the returned datatable is to use a temporary variable. However, that's a bit inconvenient.

**Question:**
Isn't there another way?

Comment: Use `po someTablePresenter.getSomeData()` in console

Comment: _However, that's a bit inconvenient._ - why?

Comment: You can show the disassembly view and set a breakpoint on a specific instruction, including the return instruction. (The debugger may let you set a breakpoint on the closing brace of the function to achieve the same result.) At that point, you may have to examine registers to see the return value.

Answer (score 16):

If you tap 'step out' then a 'return value' will appear in the debugger variable view [source](http://iosdevtips.co/post/118205216313/xcode-breakpoint-method-return-value)

Comment: O_o. 12 years working with Xcode, and I'd never seen that before. That's brilliant and comes up all the time. Thank you so much.

Answer (score -3):

When setting a break point, double click the line instead of single clicking. That should bring up this window:

[image: double-click breakpoint]

Once you see this, click add action, and you can make it automatically print out what you want to see once it hits the breakpoint.

[image: add action]

You can even set it to continue past the breakpoint so it will print and keep the program running.